# What is the alternative for Redirect in react-router-dom v 6.0.0?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

New version of react-router-dom (v6.0.0) doesn't identify "Redirect". What is the alternative for it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Redirecting alone is done via the `Navigate` component with the `replace` prop specified.

```
<Navigate replace to="/" />
```

If you want to replicate RRDv5's `Redirect` component redirecting *from* a path then you need to combine with a `Route`.

```
<Route path="/somePath" element={<Navigate replace to="/" />} />
```

- [Navigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate)
- [Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/routes)
- [Route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route)

Answer (score 6):

If you aren't server rendering your app you can still redirect on the initial render in the client like this:

```js
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

    function App() {
      return (
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/home" />} />
        </Routes>
      );
    }
```

In the above example, when someone visits `/`, they will automatically be redirected to `/home`, same as before.

Please note however that this won't work when server rendering because the navigation happens in a `React.useEffect()`.

Have a look at [Redirects in React Router v6](https://gist.github.com/mjackson/b5748add2795ce7448a366ae8f8ae3bb) for some deeper details.

Answer (score 3):

Redirecting in `react-router-dom` v6 is done with the `<Navigate>` Component with `replace` props.

**Step 1:**

```js
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
```

**Step 2:**

```js
<Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Navigate replace to='/search' />} />
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the react-router-dom teams said on the matter of redirects when that removed that API in v6: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/upgrading/reach.md#redirect-redirectto-isredirect

Answer (score 0):

If you want the application to direct you to the "Home" page when you type non-existent gibberish into the address bar, try specifying the path="*" parameter.

`<Routes> <Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/Home"/>} /> </Routes>`

Answer (score -3):

In `v6.2.*`
Just add a Route with path to `*`

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
    <Route path="expenses" element={<Expenses />} />
   
    <Route
      path="*"
      element={
        <main style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>
          <p>There's nothing here!</p>
        </main>
      }
    />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

[Official Doc](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#adding-a-no-match-route)